# TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'mat' when rotating an image in Python using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to rotate an image using Python, and I think the logic for rotating the image is correct, but whenever I try to show the the rotated image using OpenCV I get the following Error:

> TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'mat'

I am new to Python and working with OpenCV for the first time, so I don't have many ideas of this. The type of the rotated image is `numpy.ndarray` and I think OpenCV works on `nd.array`

Here is my code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def rotateToNinety(imageProcessing):
    imageProcessing = imageProcessing[::-1]
    rotatedImage = np.array([[[None for z in range(3)] for x in range(len(imageProcessing))]for y in range(len(imageProcessing[0]))])

    for i in range(len(imageProcessing[0])):
        for j in range(len(imageProcessing)):
            for k in range(3):
                rotatedImage[i][j][k] = imageProcessing[j][i][k]
    return rotatedImage


image = cv2.imread("download (2).jpg",1)

print("Original Image".center(50,"="))
print(image)

cv2.imshow("Original",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

print(type(image))


rotated_90 = rotateToNinety(image)
print("Rotated Image".center(50,"="))
print(rotated_90)

print(type(rotated_90))
cv2.imshow("rotated",rotated_90)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the way you define the empty picture is the problem, here is a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617318/python-rotate-image) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case try replacing

```py
def rotateToNinety(imageProcessing):
    imageProcessing = imageProcessing[::-1]
    rotatedImage = np.array([[[None for z in range(3)] for x in range(len(imageProcessing))]for y in range(len(imageProcessing[0]))])

    for i in range(len(imageProcessing[0])):
        for j in range(len(imageProcessing)):
            for k in range(3):
                rotatedImage[i][j][k] = imageProcessing[j][i][k]
    return rotatedImage
```

with

```py
def rotateToNinety(imageProcessing):
    h,w,c = imageProcessing.shape

    rotatedImage = np.zeros((h,w,c), dtype=np.uint8)

    imageProcessing = imageProcessing[::-1]

    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            for k in range(3):
                rotatedImage[i][j][k] = imageProcessing[j][i][k]
    return rotatedImage
```

In your case you had columns mixed with rows.

Oh and try to use `np.zeros((height, width, num_channels))` for creating blank images as much as possible.

Comment: thank u ur code helped after i changed rotatedImage = np.zeros([h,w,c], dtype=np.uint8) to rotatedImage = np.zeros([w,h,c], dtype=np.uint8) and i think there is no need of subtracting 1 (h = h-1 , w = w-1) as it gives index out of bound error

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and used:

```
image=np.uint8(image)
```

Where image is your cv.imread() object.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `image` is numpy. If not, convert it to numpy:

```
image = np.array(image)

cv2.imshow('show', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```