# How to extract vertical label and value from scanned documents?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, text-classification

I am making an document parser which extracts data fields from the documents and store them in a structured way. Each field in my dataset is horizontal which is easy to extract.

[image]

But the model fails on vertical fields for example I want to extract invoice number and date from such images which isn't possible from any type of pre-trained OCR -

[image]

Comment: I have trained MaskRCNN for the same so sharing the code might not help. The problem is with the data as the data doesn't have label and value in vertical. so it can't make vertical bounding box for label and value.

Comment: What fileformat do the original files come in? pdf? jpg?

Comment: @NikolasRieble png

Comment: this might be useful, this would rotate your image an it will fit to your code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617318/python-rotate-image

Comment: @Mohsen may i know how will that help my case?

Answer (score 0):

Convert png to pdf and then use pdf2txt.py -V

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could consider using a service like  [Amazon textract](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/)  if what you are currently using is not working. I have tested this in small samples and it seems to work well with text extraction from documents.